# Ubuntu installer cannot recognize my os while dual booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 10 on my pc and while dual booting my pc for ubuntu,installer cannot recognize my os and it doesn't give me the option to dual boot along side windows 10.please help.

Comment: Check if you don't have more than 3 primary partition. This can happen if you have 4 primary partition in MBR

Answer (score 0):

Please run a live cd of Ubuntu and install boot-repair.
Open the terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

After successfully adding and updating the repository type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```